# Use razor views with Angular2

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, razor, angular

In ASP.NET core 1 (asp.net 6) visual studio has the option to scaffold views automatically based on my data-modal classes, it knows exactly which type of editor to display based on the data type which is great.

Now I want to change the application to be SPA using angular2, is there a way for me to actually use those views, or I have to rewrite them all?.

I read an article on angular1 saying that this could be done by importing a few script libraries to the _layout file. but I can't find anything similar for angular2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After lots of searching I came to the conlution that using those views won't work, but the good news is that there's a visual studio add-on that generates typecript files based on the modal!

It could be downloaded free from [Here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e1d68248-f30e-4a5d-bf18-31399a0bcfa6)

EDIT: I was wrong, in fact it is possible to use razor views together with angular 2. see that [blog](https://ievangelistblog.wordpress.com/2016/01/13/building-an-angular2-spa-with-asp-net-5-mvc-6-web-api-2-and-typescript-1-7-5/) post for an example.

Comment: I'm happy you found my blog post. :)